# android - how to create remote xml styles

Tags: android, android-styles

I'd like the ability to change android styles remotely. The idea is to have a xml style file reside on a server and the client (mobile android device) would retrieve the remote style file at runtime and use those styles for the session.  It seems these style files get a gen file generated and this might be difficult. Can anyone recommend a solution ?

Comment: Whatever it is, it will not be "styles" in terms of style resources. Those are resources, and like all resources, they have to be compiled into the APK. There are probably some theme engines out there that will allow you to use a different system for applying a look and feel, though.

Comment: Not possible without root. Plus, its already been done. Do a search for TRDS

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the styles in the code and just send the name of that style from the server and apply that styles in the code.

Comment: yeah thats one way. but that makes my code a little more longer lol.